# drracket v6.8 nil unbound

Tags: scheme, racket

My Dr. Racket is updated to v6.8.
AFAIK nil is a language construct keyword, and should not be complained as an unbound identifier

```
#lang racket

(define (enumerate-interval low high)
  (if (> low high)
      nil
      (cons low (enumerate-interval (+ 1 low) high))))
```

The exact error message when running the definitions block is :

```
nil: unbound identifier in module in: nil
```

Is this something different with v6.8 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the release of R4RS in 1991 `nil` has not been a part of the standard. Have a look at the [PDF](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r4rs.pdf) and look at page 38 that has language changes.

`#lang racket` was originally a R5RS, but today it has evolved into a different dialect entirely. Hence its name change from Scheme to Racket. You should use the empty list literal `'()` or one of the bindings [`null`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._null%29%29), and [`empty`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._empty%29%29) in its place. `empty` is not in `racket/base` so you either need to require `racket/list` or use `#lang racket` to get the larger set of bindings to use it.

If you really want to use `nil` as a global binding representing the empty list you can just define it yourself:

```
(define nil '())
```

However a commonlisper might mistake that with the false value `#f`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I managed with the '(). Thanks.